# Push notifications don't work

Tags: android, android-emulator, push-notification

I am newbie to android. I had tried the sample given in documentation., but iam not getting any push notification only iam getting the notification icon but no content and title. Can anyone help me in getting cleared??????

1. Will push notification works in emulator or not?
2. In this sample i found a class as "Resultactivity". Purpose of using this
                 class?

I had given the code below.

```
package com.example.pushnotification;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Pushactivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pushactivity);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Check Notification")
            .setContentText("This is to test push!");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int mId = 10;
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pushactivity, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to check push on real device.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have my device now. can't we run Push notification in emulator???????

Comment: Are you getting registration id from google server?

Comment: From your code, you're not even calling the `register()` method from GCM.

Answer (score 3):

Surely it will work. I used gcm,it worked in emulator and real device.

You must install google cloud messaging from android sdk manager and use gcm.jar.

This is the best tutorial where you can test it.http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

```
Will push notification works in emulator or not?
```

**Yes** you can test `Push Notification`  in emulator , here is the  [Source](http://bhutiyagirish.wordpress.com/tag/test-push-notification-in-android-emulator/)  , Here you can find steps to display `Push Notification` inside emulator , you need to download **`gcm.jar`**

**From eclipse :**

**Window => Android SDK Manager  =>  Extras   =>  Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library**

```
In this sample i found a class as "Resultactivity". Purpose of using this class?
```

[image]

Here you can see `NotificationCompat.Builder` image , which is used to show `Notification` ,

Visit this  [Link 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) , [Link 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for more information , when you click on `Notification` you will be redirected to `ResultActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Check your *AndroidManifest.xml* file. 
(replace ****manifest-package**** with your package name)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="**manifest-package**.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="**manifest-package**.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

application...

```
    <receiver android:name=".C2DMMessageReceiver"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="**manifest-package**" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I dealt with gcm and have used the following tutorials:

Simple Tutorial: http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/

If you need a backend, which can use push, then I would recommend a "BaaS" service. The services usually have pre-installed "push modules". (Examples: apiOmat, parse...)

Answer (score 0):

GCM will work on an emulator running Android 2.2 **with Google APIs**.

> It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the
>   Google Play Store application installed, or or an emulator running
>   Android 2.2 with Google APIs. However, you are not limited to
>   deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the correction is this question: [Clicking on Notification is not starting intended activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743998/clicking-on-notification-is-not-starting-intended-activity)

The correction is to change the line:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```