# Clicking on Notification is not starting intended activity?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using GCM in my application and also using NotificationManager to Create a Notification whenever GCM message is received.Till now everything is working perfectly and GCM message is showing correctly in Notification area, but when I click on the notification it should start an activity of my application which will display the message detail which is not happening. Every-time I click on notification it does not start any activity and it remains as is.My code for creating Notification is :

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                DataAccessServer.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WarningDetails.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("warning", msg);
        bundle.putInt("warningId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for
        // the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(WarningDetails.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.weather_alert_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Weather Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);
        String selectedSound = prefs.getString("selectedSound", "");
        if (!selectedSound.equals("")) {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(selectedSound);
            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        } else {
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        }

        if (prefs.getBoolean("isVibrateOn", false)) {
            long[] pattern = { 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500 };
            mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
        }

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

I updated my code to support `Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity` just like it happens in Gmail application using the Android developers website since then it stopped working.Someone Please guide me what I am missing or doing wrong in this code.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

My problem got solved I just have to add `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` flag as well , so I replaced :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: @Saty I used it in sendNotification() method which is posted in my question

Comment: Hi you used TaskStackBuilder which needs me to require API 16 as minimum need which i dont want to do...is there any alternatives?

Comment: @Saty TaskStackBuilder is present in android support library which is  android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder. So you can use it for API 7 as well by just using support library.

Comment: how would i able to find the message in my MainActivity which is in your case is Warning?

Comment: @Saty what do you mean by find the message in your MainActivity?

Comment: if I will set the values in intent how would i be able to retrieve cause my onCreate is not called.

Comment: this was the solution for me too. But I wonder 1 month it was working without FLAG_ON_SHOT part and just stopped working

Comment: Thanks! you saved my day!

Comment: Worked for me as well! Superb!

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT will open it once, next time you press notification, it won't do anything. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT

Answer (score 27):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by adding **android:exported="true"** to the activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: this solved my problem too. Before nothing happens. With adding that line into the manifest it works:-) Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain why this works? It appears this answer is just a guess. Prove me wrong.

Comment: Strange! apparently work for me. can you describe it what is the logic behind this?

Comment: This worked for me too. The logic behind this (which I believe) is that if the activity has to be called from a different application, you should make it an exported activity. As the notification click is happening outside the app, I think we should declare the activity as exported. Reference https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported

Answer (score 2):

Here you just passed your Intent into pendingintent: see below

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Login.class);

 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
and set this contentintent into your Notification:

Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon_small)
                    .setTicker(message)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(**contentIntent**)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();
```

This may help you.

Comment: Will this supports Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity like Gmail application?

Answer (score 0):

if you launch the intended activity using **Action String** dont forget to add

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="YOUR ACTION STRING"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

inside `<activity></activity>` tag

Answer (score -1):

The activity that you want to launch has to be designated as a LAUNCHER activity in your manifest - otherwise it won't launch via a Pending Intent.  Add the following to your  in the AndroidManifext.xml

```
<activity
...
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Otherwise you will need to use an Activity that is already designated as a LAUNCHER (such as your MAIN activity)

Answer (score -2):

Do some thing like this on generateNotification() method ..

Replace your activity with Splash.Java class in it.

```
/**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //message = "vivek";
       // Log.d("anjan", message.split("~")[0]);
        //Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Log.d("anjan1", title);
        String text_message = context.getString(R.string.title_activity_main);
        Log.d("anjan1", text_message);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Splash.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }
```

Comment: Your code does not support Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity

Comment: Did you used my code in generateNotification() method. If yes then what error you are getting ?

Comment: Problem is it's not preserving the BackStack after starting Activity

Comment: Sorry I am not able to get your problem clearly. You mean to say that now on clicking notification activity is started and when we back trace from their then app crashes or some thing like that

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead of the last line :

> mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.getNotification());

Comment: But The method getNotification() from the type NotificationCompat.Builder is deprecated