# Clicking on notification on notification area does not show message in Activity

Tags: android, notifications, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I am just trying to implement the GCM in android where I am geting push notification well and good however the issue comes when I click on the notification on the notification area, it does not show up the message in TextView or on Toast.

My activity class is like this.

package com.androidhive.pushnotifications;

```
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION;
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;

// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

// Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Connection detector
ConnectionDetector cd;

public static String name;
public static String email;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xyz);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Getting name, email from intent

    Intent i = getIntent();
    /*Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message = b.getString("message");
    if(message != null)
    {
        Log.d(message, "Message Value");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message is " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }*/
    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("email");      
    //email = " ";
    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}       

/**
 * Receiving push messages
 * */
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Take appropriate action on this message
         * depending upon your app requirement
         * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
         * */

        // Showing received message
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

my GCMIntentService class is

```
package com.androidhive.pushnotifications;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;

 import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

 import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
 import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;

 public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

 private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

 public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
    ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */


@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
     Log.d("GCMIntentService", "here");
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
            errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);     

}
```

}

Comment: Why not create s small piece of code to try to get it to work.  If that small piece of code does not work, then post that small piece of code, nit your whole project.

Comment: what should I do? Please suggest I tried the suggestion by user818455 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743998/clicking-on-notification-is-not-starting-intended-activity?rq=1 however not able to make it to work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the data in a Database and later retrieve it when you open up your mainActivity or pass the data using Intent to the mainActivity.

**//Edit This is what happens when you receive the message not when you click on it, Click thing works in generateNotification function, pass "message" with your Intent and receive data with the intent**

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db.insertMsg(message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

Comment: I am doing the same if you look at the code I am calling         generateNotification(context, message); from onMessage however when it creates and open the MainActivity its shows null message.

Comment: which method in which class get called when I click on it? how would I able to get that message.

Comment: Your are doing this. Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); there are several ways one you can restart the activity and read the intents.

Comment: Please let me know one way so that I could overcome the issue I am new to android. and top of that it set two flags to intent so that activity will not start again I think please clarify 

below is two intent flag:Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: My guess was right its not reopening the MainActivity (onCreate not called) class for which if I will set the value in intent they can not be recovered that goes same with database if it is not calling onCreate how would I be able to retrieve them to show.