# GCM Notification On Click not opening the specified Activity

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting the `notification` perfectly on the device. But it does not open the mentioned `Activity`. In the log it prints the logs of the mentioned `activity` but the `MainActivity` opens. Have referred to the code from `Android docs` and changed to code according to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20744397/1928265 . But still not working.

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationCenterActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationCenterActivity.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                );

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setColor(16734816)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(body))
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setContentText(body);

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="<package name>"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!--<uses-permission android:name="<package name>.permission.permission.RECEIVE" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<package name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="<package name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="database.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="1" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.db" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        .
        .
        Other Activities
        .
        .

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationCenterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <receiver
            android:name="<package name>.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="<package name>" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="<package name>.GcmIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Paste your manifest.

Comment: Have added the manifest. When application is running in background, the specified activity opens but not when application is not running. Can you suggest a way to open a specific activity when application is not running in background?

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this

```
Random random = new Random();
int mid = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, landingactivity.class);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mid, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLargeIcon(largeicon)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallicon_push)
            .setTicker(message);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notification.setContentIntent(intent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(mid, notification.build());
```

**mid** is the Random Number to identify your notifications. it should be unique to all the notifications received.

Comment: You want me to remove TaskStakBuilder and add the Above PendingIntent? I tried this way but it didn't work. Am I doing it correct?

Comment: Just use my edited answer, u will be good to go, replace values applicable to your code.

Comment: I tried the above code but don't know. It didn't work. I took me to the MainActivity and but got logs of mentioned activity.

Comment: Are u clicking the notification when the application is in closed state? i mean the application is not running.. If the application is in running state then the specified activity will trigger for sure, else the default launcher activity only will trigger..

Comment: Yes, it worked when the application is running in background. But is there any other way if we want to direclty open the specified activity?

Comment: But why do I get logs of the specified activity even when MainActivity opens up when application is not running in background?

Comment: Yes it will, U should change the intent filter to make it open as a launcher activity..

Answer (score 0):

There could be any issue. I have faced the same problem.
Just try these steps. Glad if it works.

1. Add `android:exported="true"` for your notification activity .
2. Change your Pending intent like this `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`
   and also set  `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in activity manifest.
3. Add the intent filter to your notification activity.
   `<intent-filter>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>`

Comment: Will the above solution solve the issue of opening a specified activity when the application is not working in the background?