# Push notifications in Android emulator (5.1.1 or later)

Tags: push-notification, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I've registered for a GCM account with Google and set up my app to accept push notifications, but in the emulator I'm not receiving them (I've also tried with a 3rd party test app (https://imamraza.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/how-to-test-android-gcm-push-notification/) in case I did something wrong and that's not working either - I don't have access to a real device for testing unfortunately).

After reading some other StackOverflow answers ([Android emulator not receiving push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521600/android-emulator-not-receiving-push-notifications), [Push notifications don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713321/push-notifications-dont-work)), it seems like I need to create an emulator with `Google APIs` target. At first it wasn't there, but after adding some more packages in Android SDK Manager, I was able to see `Google APIs` as a target. Unfortunately setting the target to that results in CPU/ABI "No system images installed for this target" error:

[image]

After some more digging around, I stumbled into more SO answers, suggesting installing additional packages ([Fail to create Android virtual Device, "No system image installed for this Target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541681/fail-to-create-android-virtual-device-no-system-image-installed-for-this-targe)). That didn't help either, here is what I have installed now:

[image]
[image]

The only thing missing from my list that some others have recommended is the "Android Support" library, which apparently seems to be deprecated now according to `android list sdk -a --extended`:

```
----------
id: 140 or "extra-android-support"
    Type: Extra
    Desc: Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1 (Obsolete)
        By Android
        Install path: extras/android/support
```

What am I missing to get the Android Emulator with Google APIs target to work? It seems like a lot of the advice that I stumbled upon is dated.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

Target: Android 6.0 - API Level 23 (or other targets without "Google APIs" in it)

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)